# When scroll down in GridView and again when scroll up image are again loaded

Tags: android, gridview

When scroll down in Gridview and again when scroll up image are loaded again and again. I use Picasso library to download images.

here my code:-

```
        public class ProductsAdapterGridView extends ArrayAdapter<Products> {

        ArrayList<Products> productsList;
        LayoutInflater vi;
        int Resource;
        ViewHolder holder;
        UserSessionManager session;
        Boolean isInternetPresent = false;
        ConnectionDetector cd;
        AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();
        String product_id_grid;
        String val;

        List<String> wishArray = new ArrayList<>();
        private String file = "wishlistdata";
        String data;



        public ProductsAdapterGridView(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Products> object) {
            super(context, resource, object);
            vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            productsList = object;
            Resource = resource;
            session = new UserSessionManager(getContext());
            cd = new ConnectionDetector(getContext());
            //   this.context = context;

        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                v = vi.inflate(Resource, null);

                holder.image_product=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.image_grid_view);
                holder.product_id = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.product_id_grid_view);
                holder.product_name = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.product_name_grid_view);
                holder.product_price = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.products_price_grid_view);
                holder.product_discount = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.product_discount_grid_view);
                holder.product_special = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.product_special_grid_view);
                holder.ratingBar = (RatingBar)v.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar_grid_view);
                holder.products_off_grid_view = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.products_off_grid_view);
                holder.imageViewHeart = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.heart);

                v.setTag(holder);
            }
            else{
                holder = (ViewHolder)v.getTag();
            }
            holder.image_product.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic);



           Picasso.with(getContext()).load(productsList.get(position).getThumb()).into(holder.image_product);

            Picasso.with(getContext()).load(productsList.get(position).getHeart()).into(holder.imageViewHeart);



           // new DownloadImageTask(holder.image_product).execute(productsList.get(position).getThumb());

            //ProductsCategory.wishlistCheckModules
            holder.product_id.setText(productsList.get(position).getId());


            //Toast.makeText(getContext(), holder.product_id.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            holder.product_name.setText(productsList.get(position).getName());
            if(!productsList.get(position).getSpecial().equals("0")){

                holder.product_price.setText(getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.price) + "" + productsList.get(position).getPirce());
                //   holder.product_price.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                //   holder.product_price.setTextSize(12.0f);

                holder.product_special.setText(getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.price)+""+productsList.get(position).getSpecial());

                holder.product_price.setPaintFlags(holder.product_price.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
                holder.product_price.setTextSize(10.0f);
                holder.product_price.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
                holder.product_price.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#999999"));

                float num1 = 100-((Float.parseFloat(productsList.get(position).getSpecial())/Float.parseFloat(productsList.get(position).getPirce()))*100);
                holder.products_off_grid_view.setText(Math.round(num1) + getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.off));
                holder.products_off_grid_view.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                //  holder.products_off_grid_view.setTextSize(12.0f);

                holder.product_discount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.product_special.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.products_off_grid_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else if(!productsList.get(position).getDiscountprice().equals("0")){


                holder.product_price.setText(getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.price) + "" + productsList.get(position).getPirce());

                holder.product_discount.setText(getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.price) + "" + productsList.get(position).getDiscountprice());
                holder.product_price.setPaintFlags(holder.product_price.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
                holder.product_price.setTextSize(10.0f);
                holder.product_price.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
                holder.product_price.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#999999"));


                float num1 = 100-((Float.parseFloat(productsList.get(position).getDiscountprice())/Float.parseFloat(productsList.get(position).getPirce()))*100);
                holder.products_off_grid_view.setText(Math.round(num1) + getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.off));
                holder.products_off_grid_view.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

                holder.product_special.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.product_discount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.products_off_grid_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else {
                holder.product_price.setText(getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.price)+""+productsList.get(position).getPirce());
                holder.product_price.setPaintFlags(0);
                holder.product_price.setPaintFlags(holder.product_price.getPaintFlags() & (~ Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG));
                holder.product_price.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                holder.product_price.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                holder.product_price.setTextSize(15.0f);

                holder.products_off_grid_view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                holder.product_discount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.product_special.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            holder.ratingBar.setNumStars(Integer.parseInt(productsList.get(position).getRating()));
            holder.ratingBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.imageViewHeart.setId(position);
            holder.imageViewHeart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(session.checkLoginWishlist()){

                        product_id_grid = productsList.get(v.getId()).getId();

                        isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();

                        if(isInternetPresent){
                            new WishListProducts().execute("http://www.shoppingmazza.com/?route=feed/web_api/wishlistadd&key=test123$");
                        }
                        else {
                            alert.showAlertDialog(getContext(), "No Internet Connection",
                                    "You don't have internet connection.", false);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"You have to login first",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
            return v;
        }

        public class WishListProducts extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>{
            Boolean result = true;

            HashMap<String,String> cidValue = session.getUserDetails();
            String val;
            Boolean run = true;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                Boolean run;
                for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : cidValue.entrySet()) {
                    String key = entry.getKey().toString();;
                    String  value = entry.getValue();
                    val = value;
                    Log.d("value is",val);
                    // Toast.makeText(ProductsDetails.this,"call pre",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
                try {
                    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(params[0]);

                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<>(2);
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("product_id",product_id_grid));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cid", val));

                    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
                    int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                    if(status==200){
                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                        String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);

                        String msg = jsonObject.getString("msg");

                        Log.d("mamu",msg);

                        if(msg.equals("success")){
                            run = true;
                        }
                        else {
                            run = false;
                        }
                    }

                }catch (IOException | JSONException e){
                    result = false;
                    Log.e("Error",e.getMessage());
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                //super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
                if(result){
                    if(run){
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Products Sucessfully Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    /*    Picasso.with(getContext()).load("http://shoppingmazza.com/image/data/heart13.png").into(holder.imageViewHeart);
                        new InsertWishlistDetail().execute("http://shoppingmazza.com/?route=feed/web_api/insertappdata&key=test123$");*/

                    }
                    else {

                        new RemoveWishListProducts().execute("http://www.shoppingmazza.com/?route=feed/web_api/wishlistremove&key=test123$");

                    }
                } else{
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Somthing is bad happen",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
        public class InsertWishlistDetail extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>{
            Boolean result = true,run;
            String android_id;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                android_id = Settings.Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(),
                        Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
                try {
                    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(params[0]);

                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<>(2);
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("deviceid", android_id));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid",product_id_grid));


                    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
                    if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()==200){

                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                        String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);

                        if(jsonObject.getString("msg").equals("success")){
                            run = true;
                        }
                        else {
                            run = false;
                        }

                    }

                }catch (IOException | JSONException e){
                    result = false;
                }

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
               // super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
                if(result){
                    if(run){

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public class RemoveWishListProducts extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>{
            Boolean result;
            HashMap<String,String> cidValue = session.getUserDetails();
            String val;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : cidValue.entrySet()) {
                    String key = entry.getKey().toString();;
                    String  value = entry.getValue();
                    val = value;
                    Log.d("value is",val);
                    // Toast.makeText(ProductsDetails.this,"call pre",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
                try{
                    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(params[0]);

                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<>(2);
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("product_id",product_id_grid));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cid",val));
                    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
                    int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                    if(status==200) {
                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                        String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);

                        if(jsonObject.getString("msg").equals("error")){
                            result = false;
                        }else {
                            result = true;
                        }
                    }
                }catch (IOException |JSONException e){
                    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                if(result){
                   // reload();
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Item is sucessfully Removed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    Picasso.with(getContext()).load("http://shoppingmazza.com/image/data/heart296.png").into(holder.imageViewHeart);

                    new WishlistRemove().execute("http://shoppingmazza.com/?route=feed/web_api/deleteappdata&key=test123$");
                  //  holder.imageViewHeart.setImageResource(R.drawable.wishlistcat);
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Somthing is bad happened",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }

        public class WishlistRemove extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>{
            Boolean result = true;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
                try {
                    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(params[0]);

                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<>(1);
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", product_id_grid));

                    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
                    if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()==200){

                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                        String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);

                        Log.d("jo",jsonObject+"");
                    }

                }catch (IOException | JSONException e){
                    result = false;
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
               // super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
                if(result){

                }
            }
        }

        static class ViewHolder{
            public ImageView image_product;
            public TextView  product_id;
            public TextView  product_name;
            public TextView  product_price;
            public TextView  product_discount;
            public TextView  product_special;
            public RatingBar ratingBar;
            public TextView  products_off_grid_view;
            public ImageView imageViewHeart;
        }

    }
```

I am new in android developing.Anyone can help me to solve my problem.Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you giving resize parameter to picasso? do you have width/height set to wrap_content for the image views?

Comment: Also mentions whats the target imageview's width/height

Comment: No I don't re-size images i have set  width/height wrap_content.

Comment: yea thats why the whole image is being loaded as is, hence going over cache size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually this happens on Picasso when the image sizes exceed the cache size, i.e if you load images without resizing to lower resolution to reduce their size in memory. Picasso has an internal LruCache, with a fixed max size, so when multiple "huge" images are loaded the previous images are discarded from memory in order to not go over the cache size limit.

The methods to go around this are

- Increase Picasso's Lrucache size.
- Resize image to lower resolution before loading them.

**Edit**

Change picasso cache size. Remeber you have to put this code in your application class, and ensure that this instantiation is a singleton. And you need to use this Picasso class everywhere else. I would **NOT** recommend changing cache size. Instead try the second method method

```
int maxSize = MAX_CACHE_SIZE;
Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(context)
                        .memoryCache(new LruCache(maxSize)).build();
```

Resize image size

```
Picasso
    .with(context)
    .load(UsageExampleListViewAdapter.eatFoodyImages[0])
    .resize(600, 200) // resizes the image to these dimensions (in pixel). does not respect aspect ratio
    .into(imageViewResize);
```

Comment: How to increase Picasso's Lrucache size.

Comment: what do you mean set loader?

Comment: yes when images are downloading that time show loader.

Comment: this merits another question entirely.

Comment: if this answer solved your question, then mark it correct so that it helps future readers and also helps me

Comment: this is related to picasso yes, but its not related to this current question, and what you ask for is a loaded question and there isn't any native support by picasso for using progress bars at least to my knowledge, so there are plenty of hacks for this which I can list out to you and you choose whichever suits you best, and i dont want to add that huge wall of text to this answer

Comment: @Annajain if you have asked that question put a link to it here in the comment, ill answer it